# How to make angular pipe for filtering array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, pipe

This is array I want to filter

```
[
    0: {id: 1, name: "Berlin",}
    1: {id: 2, name: "Proffesor",}
    2: {id: 4, name: "Oslo",}
    3: {id: 6, name: "Denver",}
]
```

This is array for filter

```
 [6, 16, 2, 10, 24]
```

This is my pipe

```
export class ChatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(user: Users[], args: any): any { //for users i use first array and for args I use second
    if (!user || !args) {
      return user;
      
  }
  
  let filteri = user.filter(users => users.id == args);
  
  return filteri;
};

}
```

I want to filter first array using values from another. Can anyone help me?

Comment: ```let filteri = user.filter(item => args.includes(item.id));``` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this :

```
// let filteri = user.filter(users => users.id == args);
// return filteri;
return (user || []).filter((item: any) => (args || []).includes(item.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

*Event though you are not telling us your desire output, I guess that you wanna filter the first array with the values of the second one by id.*

First of all create your users array to be like an array:

Instead of this:

```
[
    0: {id: 1, name: "Berlin",}
    1: {id: 2, name: "Proffesor",}
    2: {id: 4, name: "Oslo",}
    3: {id: 6, name: "Denver",}
]
```

Make it like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "Berlin"},
    {id: 2, name: "Proffesor"},
    {id: 4, name: "Oslo"},
    {id: 6, name: "Denver"},
]
```

After that your pipe should be like this:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'filterUsersByIds',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterUsersByIdsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(users: user[], filters: number[]): any {
        if (!users || !filters) {
            return users;
        }
        
        return users.filter(user => filters.some(x => user.id === x));
    }
}
```

*PS: Don't forget to declare the pipe in a module before using the pipe in your HTML.*